# Remove overprint with Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Good afternoon!

We are preparing a banner in Inkscape.

One of the requirements of thypography is that all overprints must be removed.

How to do this in Inkscape?

I have tried to do this through *Path --> Difference*, but when there is a lot of elements, this is not a solution...

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two general options:

- with Boolean operations. There is an extension that can do it faster for you:
  https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-pathops
- by making a bitmap copy (i.e. Edit > Make a Bitmap copy, or export and import a PNG), and vectorizing that (uncheck the option 'stack scans')

Although, as long as you don't plan to cut your result from real materials (plotter foil), I don't see why those would have to be removed (edit: maybe you're using spot colors?). This would usually be done software-side by the printer's office.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried both listed options, but both of them have disadvantages: in the first case (inx-pathops) Difference acts on just first and last objects, while in the second case (Bitmap) large white gaps appear. The results are shown here, http://www.bildites.lv/images/7jmth9s5/141552/original.png. Are there ways to improve them?

Comment: > maybe you're using spot colors?
Probably yes. Actually, I am not a specialist in this. I conclude this from their requirement to use CMYK and set black color as composite of four components of this model.

Comment: The multi difference extension I linked acts on all selected objects. The top most object is subtracted from all objects that are below and selected.

Comment: For trace bitmap, use a higher resolution png (e.g. export at high resolution). Then also play with the options tab in the trace bitmap dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I recently getting to know with Scribus software, which is free, supports opening or importing svg files, and in the Properties and in the color section, you can choose whether it is Knockout or Overprint.

so, you can open Inkscape svg files into Scribus and use the Overprint option there.

Of course, I don't know if it can be used in banner printing or not, but it will probably be useful for magazines and publications. Thank you.

[Scribus site](https://www.scribus.net)